# How can I make a criteria in an excel forumla reference text in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, criteria, sumifs, excel-indirect

I am using a SUMIFs formula in excel. One of my criteria consists of text, but the text will vary for every row I am applying this formula too. Rather than typing out that text for each column, I'd like to find a way to include in my formula the reference for where that text comes from, and have excel grab it for each row.

***This picture shows what I am currently working with.***
[image: This picture shows what I am currently working with.]

The last term in the formula is "BT-107-141-1". That is also the value of A2 in this sheet. Rather than typing "BT-107-141-1" (and doing the same thing for every row I have), can I direct excel to use whatever value is in A2 as the criteria in this formula?

I was trying to use INDIRECT, but couldn't get it to work. Something like "VALUE($A2)" might work?

Please let me know if you have any questions, I would really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Comment: Surprisingly, the simplest solution was correct here. All I had to do was type A2 as the criteria (no quotes).

Comment: Just use `A2` directly as criteria rather than `"BT-107-141-1"`.